# Error 404--Not Found - Unable to call REST WebService

Tags: web-services, rest

I am not lucky so far to get the solution for the below error,

"Error 404--Not Found

From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

10.4.5 404 Not Found

The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.
If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address."

but no luck and so posting this question here.

I have a requirement to download a image file from the server location using RESTFul Web Services. So, i created a REST WS in eclipse as below steps,

1. Eclipse --> File --> New Dynamic WebProject
2. Created a service class called "DownloadWebService" in src
3. Added Jersey libraries in Java Resources --> Libraries folder.
4. Created index.jsp and web.xml in WebContent folder.
5. Project right click --> Export--> WAR file.

DownloadWebService:

```
package com.downloadfile.webservice;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
@Path("/files")   
public class DownloadWebService { 

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "/ngs/app/alect/test";  
    @POST   
    @Path("/image")   
    @Produces("image/png")    
    public Response getFile() { 
        System.out.println("************");
        Logger.getLogger("############");
        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);    
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        System.out.println("testing Web Service..."+FILE_PATH);
        System.out.println("");
        response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"test.png\"");  
        return response.build();     

    }  
 }
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.downloadfile.webservice.DownloadWebService</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>     
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="rest/files/image">Download Image File</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to deploy this WAR application in WebLogic server and when i hit the test below link, it's taking me the index.jsp file in the browser which is expected and it's correct. After i click the link "Download Image File", its forwarding the below URL in the browser

http://alecitapp.corp.apple.com:7007/AppleDownloadWebService/rest/files/image

It's throwing the above said 404 --Not found error.

Am i missing something here? Not even seeing the Service class is being called? Index page is coming up and on click the download link it should go to the Service class but it didn't.

Please correct me if i am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Karthik.

Comment: Shoudn't your class extend a Servlet or something?

Comment: Nope. It's a web service class. Does it need to extend any servlet class or anything? Please let me know.

Comment: http://alecitapp.corp.apple.com:7007/rest/files/image  try hitting this link and tell me know if this solves your issue. Some servers take the project display name as part of the url. some don't... i personally haven'y worked with weblogic so let me know... if this works

Comment: Hmm, upon research. Maybe not. In any case, you might want to try without `@Path("/image")`, and just test the `/rest/files`

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Same error with this link as well. :(

Comment: is your server running on the correct port number??

Comment: @cricket_0007 -  i removed the @Path("/image") and still the same error messages.

Comment: @Abhishek - Yes, since its running in correct port, i am able to get the index.html file in the browser. After i click the download link in the index.jsp page, it's directing to the browser URL as http://alecitapp.corp.apple.com:7007/AppleDownloadWebService/rest/files/    then getting the error message,

Comment: @cricket_0007 - - how to see if the control is coming to the web service class or not? i mean /rest/files or /rest/test  till to service class at least?  Even i tries to change it as pdf no luck. .. any idea please? or share any sample REST code that would be also helpful.   @Path("/test")  
public class DownloadWebService { 
 @Path("/pdf")  
    @Produces("application/pdf") 
    public Response getFile() { 
     System.out.println("************");
     Logger.getLogger("############");
        }

Comment: change the servlet-class to ""   <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  ""  in your web.xml

Comment: @Abhishek - its still not able to access the service. I changed it as,

Comment: <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>  
        <param-value>com.downloadfile.webservice/</param-value>  
    </init-param>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
  </servlet>  
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>

Comment: @Karthik Pon did you find a solution to this?